# Having problem in connecting my SQL Database to my Chrome extension using XAMPP

Tags: php, html, sql-server, google-chrome-extension, xampp

I am trying to connect to my SQL database using (XAMPP-phpmyadmin) from my google chrome extension. 
I am getting the following error:-

(Your file was not found It may have been moved or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

I changed my code from (insert.php to data.php) but my data is not getting stored in database. When I click submit button in my extension, I am getting my php script i.e data.php as the popup.

```
 (data.php)

 <pre>
 <?php
 $database="uppercase";

 $name=$_POST['name'];

 mysql_connect(localhost);
 @mysql_select_db($database) ;

 $query = "INSERT INTO urltable VALUES ('','$name')";
 mysql_query($query);

 mysql_close();

 ?>
 </pre>



 (popup.html)

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min">
    </script>

 <script src="popup.js">
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="Submit">
    </form>

  </body>

  </html> 


 (manifest.json)
  {
 "manifest_version": 2,

 "name": "My Launcher",
 "description": "Quick launch lol Media",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },
 "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
 "permissions": [
  "tabs","http://localhost/*"
 ],
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"],
    "persistent": false
 }
 }
```

I am basically taking an input from the user and trying to send it to my table "urltable" in my database.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Be sure to use prepared statements and parameter binding, so **you'll never have to worry about quoting issues again.**

Comment: Also, you're submitting your form to `insert.php`, but your insert code is located in `data.php`, thus getting a File Not Found error.

Comment: `action="http://localhost/insert.php"` is probably what you meant since the popup runs in its own chrome-extension:// URL. However it'll replace your popup page contents with the answer, which is probably not what you want. Usually people do it with XMLHttpRequest or fetch or jQuery.ajax.

Comment: I changed my code from (insert.php to data.php) but my data is not getting stored in database. When I click submit button in my extension, I am getting my php script i.e data.php as the popup.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min">
        </script>

     <script src="popup.js">
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>

        <form action="insert.php" method="post">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="name">
            <input type="Submit">
        </form>
      </body>
   </html>
```

In your Form action, the action link is still: "insert.php" change it to (data.php).

```
<form action="data.php" method="post">
```

You are trying to send a POST request to a not existing page.